EMAIL IS NOT GOING IF ATTACHING 500KB or Above
I am trying to upload file of size between 1MB and 2MB using LWC component and after upload saving the same file as an attachment and sending it in an single email as an attachment.
I am able to upload file but when but if file size is more than 500KB then email is failing but for smaller sizes like 250KB or 300KB email is going with an attachment.
I tried different email services as well like yop mail and goggle mail but it is not the issue.
I can understand large size files will not go as email attachment but at least 1MB file it should allow
In email logs getting below error
Delivery Status Notification - 552 Message exceeds allowed size
421 Error
Find my code below
HTML FILE:
 <lightning-file-upload
            label="Upload Files"
            name="fileUploader"
            accept={acceptedFormats}
            record-id={recordId}
            onuploadfinished={handleUploadFinished}
            >
            </lightning-file-upload>

APEX :
list<string> toEmailList=new list<string>();
toEmailList.add('taugupeipodu-9832@yopmail.com');
contentversion cv= [select Id,ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId from contentversion where ContentDocumentId='069F7000002Fyl0'];
messaging.singleemailmessage conemail=new messaging.singleemailmessage();
conemail.subject='AVOID TEST SUBJECT';
conemail.setToAddresses(toEmailList);
conemail.htmlbody='<p>It is with attachment</p>';
system.debug('cv.ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId====>>>>'+cv.ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId);
conemail.setEntityAttachments(new list<string>{cv.ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId});

Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { conemail });

JS FILE:
    get acceptedFormats() {
        return ['.pdf', '.png','.jpg','.jpeg'];
    }
    handleUploadFinished(event) {
        debugger;
        const uploadedFiles = event.detail.files;
        this.attachmentId = uploadedFiles[0].documentId;
        getSizeMethod({ inputParameter: this.attachmentId })
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            console.log('Send email with attachment');
            this.sendType='Send As Attachment';
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });

        let uploadedFileNames = '';
        for(let i = 0; i < uploadedFiles.length; i++) {
            uploadedFileNames += uploadedFiles[i].name + ', ';
        }
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Success',
                message: uploadedFiles.length + ' Files uploaded Successfully: ' + uploadedFileNames,
                variant: 'success',
            }),
        );
        
    }

